# why is this JavaScript slowing down my web page

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JavaScript and i have written a function that refreshes nodes on a web age every 5 seconds. I load a json file of 68 bytes in size and parses the html changing data.

After about 20 second the age freezes and slowing down the browser, also the class changes are not happening.

I don't know if i have a memory leak or if i should just get the server to send the data.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.getJSON("/Assets/inplay.json", function(data){
        var j_data = JSON.parse(data);
        var Curr = [];
        $.each(j_data, function(key, value){
            Curr.push(value._id.$oid);
            chk = document.getElementById('HT-'+value._id.$oid);
            if (chk == null){
                $('#in-play').append(addRow(value));
            } else {
                var prefixes = ['GT-', 'HG-', 'HDA-', 'HA-', 'HP-', 'HOT-', 'HOffT-', 'HPI-', 'Fav-', 'AG-', 'ADA-', 'AA-', 'AP-', 'AOT-', 'AOffT-', 'API-', 'HMO-', '025-', '035-', '045-', 'AMO-', 'U25-', 'U35-', 'U45-', 'DMO-'];
                var values = [value.Stats[0].gt, value.Stats[0].hg, chkVal(value.Stats[0],'Dangerous_Attacks', 0), chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'Attacks', 0), chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'Possession', 0), chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'On_Target', 0), chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'Off_Target', 0), chkVal2(value.HomePI, 'PI'), chkVal3(value.Fav), value.Stats[0].ag, chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'Dangerous_Attacks', 1), chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'Attacks', 1), chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'Possession', 1), chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'On_Target', 1), chkVal(value.Stats[0], 'Off_Target', 1), chkVal2(value.AwayPI, 'PI'), marketsFunc(value, "MATCH_ODDS", 0), marketsFunc(value, "OVER_UNDER_25", 1), marketsFunc(value, "OVER_UNDER_35", 1), marketsFunc(value, "OVER_UNDER_45", 1), marketsFunc(value, "MATCH_ODDS", 1), marketsFunc(value, "OVER_UNDER_25", 0),  marketsFunc(value, "OVER_UNDER_35", 0),  marketsFunc(value, "OVER_UNDER_45", 0), marketsFunc(value, "MATCH_ODDS", 2)];
                for (var i = 0, len = prefixes.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (values[i] != null && document.getElementById(prefixes[i]+value._id.$oid) != null) {
                        //console.log(prefixes[i]+value._id.$oid);
                        //console.log(values[i]);

                        if (prefixes[i] == 'GT-' && value.Tactics != null){
                            if(value.Tactics.indexOf("HT-LTD") != -1 && values[i] == '45:00') {
                                class_n = document.getElementById('HT-'+value._id.$oid).classList;
                                class_n.add('HT-LTD');
                                class_n = document.getElementById('AT-'+value._id.$oid).classList;
                                class_n.add('HT-LTD');
                            } else if (classArr.indexOf("HT-LTD") != -1 && values[i] != '45:00') {
                                class_n = document.getElementById('HT-'+value._id.$oid).classList;
                                class_n.remove('HT-LTD');
                                class_n = document.getElementById('AT-'+value._id.$oid).classList;
                                class_n.remove('HT-LTD');
                            }
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'HPI-' && values[i] > 6) {
                            class_n = document.getElementById('HT-'+value._id.$oid).classList;
                            class_n.add('HI-PRESSURE');
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'API-' && values[i] > 6) {
                            //console.log('bob');
                            class_n = document.getElementById('AT-'+value._id.$oid).classList;
                            class_n.add('HI-PRESSURE');
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'HG-' && values[i] != document.getElementById(prefixes[i]+value._id.$oid).innerHTML) {
                            document.getElementById('HG-'+value._id.$oid).className = 'GOAL';
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'AG-' && values[i] != document.getElementById(prefixes[i]+value._id.$oid).innerHTML) {
                            document.getElementById('AG-'+value._id.$oid).className = 'GOAL';
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'HG-' && document.getElementById('HG-'+value._id.$oid).className == 'GOAL') {
                            document.getElementById('HG-'+value._id.$oid).className = 'OLD-GOAL';
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'AG-' && document.getElementById('AG-'+value._id.$oid).className == 'GOAL') {
                            document.getElementById('AG-'+value._id.$oid).className = 'OLD-GOAL';
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'HG-' && document.getElementById('HG-'+value._id.$oid).className == 'OLD-GOAL') {
                            document.getElementById('HG-'+value._id.$oid).className = '';
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'AG-' && document.getElementById('AG-'+value._id.$oid).className == 'OLD-GOAL') {
                            document.getElementById('AG-'+value._id.$oid).className = '';
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'HPI-' && values[i] < 7) {
                            class_n = document.getElementById('HT-'+value._id.$oid).classList;
                            class_n.remove('HI-PRESSURE');
                        } 
                        if (prefixes[i] == 'API-' && values[i] , 7) {
                            class_n = document.getElementById('AT-'+value._id.$oid).classList;
                            class_n.remove('HI-PRESSURE');
                        }
                        //console.log('ya');
                        document.getElementById(prefixes[i]+value._id.$oid).innerHTML = values[i];
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        var myGames = [];
        var cl = '';
        var n = [];
        var table = document.getElementById("in-play");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
           //iterate through rows
           //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
           if (row.className == 'even') {

                n = row.id.split('-');
                cl = n[n.length - 1];
                myGames.push(cl);
                //console.log(cl);

           }
        }
        //console.log(myGames);
        for(var i = 0; i < myGames.length; i++) {
            if (Curr.indexOf(myGames[i]) === -1 && myGames[i] != ""){
                //console.log(myGames[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById('HT-'+myGames[i]);
                if (row != null) {
                    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
                }
                row = document.getElementById('AT-'+myGames[i]);
                if (row != null) {
                    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
                }
                var tr = document.getElementsByClassName('market-'+myGames[i]);
                var table = document.getElementById('in-play');

                for(var i = tr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                    table.deleteRow(tr[i].rowIndex);
                }
                tr = document.getElementsByClassName('form-'+myGames[i]);
                table = document.getElementById('in-play');

                for(var i = tr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                    table.deleteRow(tr[i].rowIndex);
                }
            }
        }

    });
}, 5000);
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you try using your browser's developer tools to see if you have a memory leak?

Comment: I tried but the browser completely crashed, i used chrome and firefox same happened with both browsers

Comment: Restart the browser, reload the page, and bring up the developer tools right away.  Increase the interval to more than 5 seconds if it's going down too fast.

Comment: I doubt that this is the real code. You're using `$.getJSON()` hence `data` should already be parsed and `var j_data = JSON.parse(data);` should throw a syntax error.

Comment: @Andreas if i just use `$.getJSON()` i throw a type error saying it is a string.

Comment: Start debugging your code. Remove everything but the `.getJSON()` call itself (without the code in it's callback). If it works, add an empty `.each()`, if it works add the "body" of the `.each()`, if it works ... Until it doesn't work anymore. Add some `console.log()`s to see where and when it stops working...